# Warcraft: Orcs & Humans - Campaign and Mission Order

Tags: warcraft

I was wondering in which order I should play the missions of Warcraft: Orcs & Humans (the first title of the series). The game offers you to play both, the orc as well as the human campaign right from the beginning. However, the orc campaign appears first in the menu.

As far as I understand, the storylines of the orc and human campaigns run in parallel mission per mission, with the ability to win the war with either the orcs or the humans in the end (just like alternative endings). According to this, a GameFAQ [Walkthrough by XellKhaar](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/565021-warcraft-orcs-and-humans/faqs/54781) (II. Basics - 2.05: Before you play) suggests to play the campaign missions alternating, starting with human level 1 then orc level 1 and so on.

However, one questions remains: Is there any good reason to start the alternation with the humans? Or are the missions maybe so much in parallel that it doesn't make any difference story-wise and I could also start with the orcs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with humans is a good idea, because that way your last mission will be for orks. And canonically orks won the first war.

First several mission are almost exactly same and serve more for exposition and not drive story in any way. You both starting with building farms to support army, you both travel to the

> Deadmines (however for different reasons)

Later, path would bring you to the different parth of Azeroth, but missions would still be symmetrical: you would have to do essentually the same thing for both sides.

If you are not afraid that storylines will mix, play alternating sides. Just remember that most important events in both campaings have happened canonically, so you are not likely to confuse which turn of event is "true".

Comment: Sounds reasonable to play the canonically ending last. Good point.

Comment: And thank you very much for the additional remarks.